# Can I use an ÖBB ticket for an alternative international route?

Tags: trains, poland, austria, czech-republic

I need to take a train from Vienna to Krakow. There is a direct train (EC 106) however it is reasonably likely that I will not arrive at the train station in time to catch it (for reasons beyond my control). The next train is 3 hours later and includes a change in Breclav (the Breclav-Krakow train is an EC130 from Budapest).

The standard ticket for the EC106 says that it is valid for the whole day and for any train. However it is not possible to buy a ticket for the EC 130 train on the ÖBB website. This brings me to my question: can I use the standard ticket for the EC 106 on the EC 130? Or does this only work for Austrian trains? Alternatively is there anywhere I can buy a ticket which is valid for both connections?

Comment: I don't quite understand. which part of it is the night train? what trip did you get from obb?

Comment: The night train gets me to Vienna. It is not part of my problem, simply a probable cause of delays

Comment: are you buying the EC106 through OBB? is it part of your NJ trip, or is it a separate booking?

Comment: I found the mentioned standard ticket on the OBB website.  This part of my journey will be booked separately from the NJ though.  I will edit my question to remove the mention of NJ and avoid confusion

Comment: odd. polrail doesn't seem to be aware of the EC130 either. As ÖBB can't apparently sell you a ticket for the EC130, I wouldn't think any ÖBB ticket could be valid on it. mav.hu sells ticket for the EC130, but not if you're not travelling to or from Hungary.

Answer (score 3):

To the best of my research, bahn.de sells "Wien - Krakow" (via Breclav, using the EC 130) as "Flexpreis Europa" and presents it as "Unrestricted choice of trains".

This *looks like it should* be indicating that you can take the EC106 with this ticket as well, but more digging into detailed terms and conditions is required to confirm it.

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking you do not buy a ticket for a train. So you do not buy a ticket for EC 106. What you buy is a ticket "Vienne to Krakow". And the default is for such tickets to be valid on all train on the route.

Of course if you buy a discounted ticket it can come with the stipulation that you must try to be on the train you selected during booking.

What you can do is select EC 106, and just book a ticket for it. If your Night Train is on time you take that train. If it is delayed you are entitled to take the next available train. And that even with a discounted ticket.

Comment: *you are entitled to take the next available train* — maybe; on trains with mandatory reservations (don't know if that applies here), you might need to buy a new reservation and can then try to claim that back, and one might reach a discussion about whether two seperate tickets count as one journey for the purpose of delay rights.